# How can I pass an ID to my selectcommand to filter out my records?

Tags: asp.net

I have this code example.  This web page would be called by another webpage that is passing an ID through the url e.g.  `http://localhost:49780/bookingform.aspx?passedid=8`

How can I get that ID to my selectcommand to filter out my records? e.g. ProductID <= passedid

Code:

```
<%@ page language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head>
    <title>Repeater.DataSourceID Property Example</title>
</head>

  <body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">

      <h3>Repeater.DataSourceID Property Example</h3>

      <asp:repeater id="Repeater1"       
        datasourceid="SqlDataSource1"
        runat="server">

        <headertemplate>
          <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <td><b>Product ID</b></td>
              <td><b>Product Name</b></td>
            </tr>
        </headertemplate>

        <itemtemplate>
          <tr>
            <td> <%# Eval("ProductID") %> </td>
            <td> <%# Eval("ProductName") %> </td>
          </tr>
        </itemtemplate>

        <footertemplate>
          </table>
        </footertemplate>
      </asp:repeater>

            <asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1"          
            connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnection%>" 
        selectcommand="SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM [Products] Where ProductID <= 10"
        runat="server">
      </asp:sqldatasource>

    </form>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Regards

Tea

Comment: you can assign your querystring to a property in the page and add filter to your select query with productid= <%=Property%>

Comment: Can you give an example of a property on a page?  Sorry bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can pass query string to the sqlconection as parameter

```
 <asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1"          
        connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindConnection%>" 
    selectcommand="Procedure Name" CommandType="Procedure"
    runat="server">
   <SelectParameters>
  <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProductID " QueryStringField="passedidc" Type="Int32" />
   <SelectParameter>
  </asp:sqldatasource>
```

only problem is rather than using query on page you need to use procedure and pass procedure name to selectcommand.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int _querystring=string.empty;

public int QueryString
{
get
{
return _querystring;
}
set
{
_querystring=value;
}

QueryString=Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["passedid"].ToString());
```

Pass this value in your code

```
selectcommand='SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM [Products] Where ProductID="<%=QueryString>"'
```

Comment: sorry fro the type: write  

private int _querystring;

Comment: Invalid column name '<%=QueryString%>'. ?  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm trying this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644982/parameter-error-when-trying-to-build-a-selectcommand

Comment: Great! you got your answer then.