# Parameter error when trying to build a selectcommand

Tags: asp.net

I'm passing a value thru a querystring, I want that value to be part of my selectcommand to build my GridView.  But I'm getting the following error.  Any ideas how to fix?

Error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '<%=QueryString2%>' to data type int.

C#:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        QueryString=Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["tourid"]);
    }

    private int _querystring;

    public int QueryString
    {
        get
        {
            return _querystring;
        }
        set
        {
            _querystring = value;
        }
    }
```

ASPX:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ChinatowndbConnString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vwSchedule] Where TourId=@tid">

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter  DefaultValue="<%=QueryString%>" Name="tid" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: put a break point and see what is inside `Request.QueryString["tourid"]`

Comment: QueryString is 2, if I highlight over Request.QueryString {tourid=2}

Comment: Replace please " on ' in  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ChinatowndbConnString %>"  and DefaultValue="<%=QueryString%>"

Comment: My connectionstring is fine.  I use it on other webpages in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `<%= ... %>` to assign the value of a server-control property. As a result, your `DefaultValue` is being set to the literal string `"<%=QueryString%>"`, which is not a valid integer.

Try using a [`QueryStringParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter.aspx) instead:

```
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:QueryStringParameter  
      Name="tid" 
      DbType="Int32" 
      QueryStringField="tourid"
   />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: No, the `QueryStringParameter` will take care of that for you.